# Toggling divs not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to toggle a div to make it visible, then not visible yet the button I've created does not ever execute the code. I've tried putting an onclick event into the button and just linking it to a js script. That did not work, so my most recent attempt included me writing the javascript in all jquery hoping that avoiding the onclick event in the button would solve the issue. It did not however, so I'm stuck without any idea how to solve this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <title>New Tab</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="page">
    <center><iframe name="web" src="http://www.bing.com/" height="70%" width="70%">Please download a browser that supports iframes.</iframe></center>
    <center>
        <button type="submit" onclick="web.history.back();">Back</button>
        <button id="hide_btn">Hide</button>
        <button type="submit" onclick="web.history.forward();">Forward</button>
    </center>   
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#hide_btn').click(function () {
            $('#page').toggle();
        });
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works fine when I run it here it hides the div

Comment: Running it from local file system ?

Comment: I am indeed running it for a local file system, if that's the issue I'll just punch myself in the face now.

Comment: You *do* need to put `http://` before the jQuery script call ***if*** you're running the page from your local hard drive instead of an internet URL.

Comment: _don't punch yourself in the face, that hurt's_ -------  you need to put `http:` in your  jquery src

Comment: I think somebody owes @Spokey an apology...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're running it locally you need to add `http://` of the script source.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The automatic protocol detection achieved by leaving the http or https off only works when run from a server. Otherwise, the browser is trying to use file:// (or other equivalent local file protocol) which causes the failure.

Comment: Truly never knew this. Actually learned something new today woohoo.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but different browsers implement a different default behaviour for the HTML `<button />` element so is it defaulting to a submit button and reloading the page instead of running the jQuery?

I mean if you add 'type=button' to the button mark-up does it help?